# How can I create a pie chart of species recorded so that the colours match the symbology of the GPS points displayed in my map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, graph

I have created a map in ArcMap 10.3 showing the locations of bat sightings in a borough in London, the symbology set to show the different bat species recorded. I want to have a pie chart as an insert showing the proportion that each species makes of all the recorded sightings so that the colours match the symbology of the map. Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but you'll get a better-looking result if you export your data to Excel or something, create the pie chart there, then copy and paste it into your layout.

Comment: Thanks - would it just be a matter of manually matching the colours?

Comment: Out of interest how would you do it in ArcMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table view in ArcGIS, click Table Options > Create Graph:

[image]

You will need to create a field and calculate your bat species proportion first,  I'm pretty sure ArcGIS can't do that on the fly in the Graph tool. Set the graph type to Pie, the Value field to your Proportion field, and the Sort field to the species name. For Color, select "Match with Layer" (it should default to this) to make the pie slices use the same colors as the species symbols.

As I mentioned in comments though, ArcGIS' graph tools aren't that great, if you'd like to get a better-looking graph, I'd export your data to Excel or something and create your graph there. As you mentioned, you'd need to match the colors manually using the RGB or HSL codes.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's been driving me crazy - I will give both a go.

Comment: @Ella You're welcome. If you found that helpful, you should click the up-vote arrow next to the answer. You can also check the checkmark to mark this answer as "accepted" if it solves the problem. Welcome to the site.